# Getting grid (hub-node)information from selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Is there any API for selenium in java for getting hub-node details, what I mean is to get the number of active node, IP address, browsers configured in each node etc. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I got one solution. It works only if you know the hub & node machine url

Object object= client.getForObject(baseUrl+"/grid/api/proxy?id="+ipaddress[i], Object.class);

Here client is an instance of RESTTemplate class of spring frame work.
BaseUrl:_url of hub
ipaddress[i]:-Node machine IP.

Result should be like

```
<200 OK, { success=true, msg=proxy found !, id=http://192.168.3.37:5555, request={class=org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest, id=null, name=null, description=null, configuration={port=5555, servlets=[], host=192.168.3.37, Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Anoop\IEdriver\IEDriverServer.exe=, cleanUpCycle=5000, Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Anoop\chromeDriver\chromedriver.exe=, browserTimeout=0, hubHost=localhost, registerCycle=5000, capabilityMatcher=org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher, newSessionWaitTimeout=-1, hub=http://localhost:4444/grid/register, url=http://192.168.3.37:5555, remoteHost=http://192.168.3.37:5555, register=true, throwOnCapabilityNotPresent=true, nodePolling=5000, proxy=org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy, browser=browserName=firefox, maxSession=5, role=node, jettyMaxThreads=-1, hubPort=4444, timeout=300000}, capabilities=[{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, platform=WIN8_1, browserName=firefox}, {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, platform=WIN8_1, browserName=chrome}, {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, platform=WIN8_1, browserName=internet explorer}]}},{Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[1185], Server=[Jetty(7.x.y-SNAPSHOT)]}>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

`curl http://myhub.com:4444/grid/api/proxy?id=http://172.22.25.164:5555`

172.22.25.164 - ip of selenium node

output >>>

```
{"success":true,... }
```